# Are delayed abilities bad in turn-based strategy games?

Tags: game-mechanics, turn-based, turn-based-strategy

In my PvP turn-based strategy, one of the balancing mechanisms for separating stronger from weaker abilities is their "delay", which is the number of turns it will take to actually execute that ability, from when it was commanded. For example, if you cast an ability with delay = 1, that unit won't use it until the start of your next turn. Most abilities have delay = 0, meaning it's used right when the command is given. It is clear when a unit is "casting" a delayed ability; they have an ongoing casting animation, there are tick marks above their head to count how many turns left for casting, and when you click on them, you see which tiles are targeted.

It's similar to "casting time" in Final Fantasy Tactics.

It serves several purposes in my game. For one thing, I need to balance stronger vs weaker abilities somehow, and there's already a lot of other resources to keep track of (action points, gold, etc). I don't want to clutter the game with more resources, such as mana on individual units. Units can have "cooldown" (number of turns where they can't be used) after being used, so moving units into enemy territory with cooldown can be dangerous, because they're vulnerable to the more powerful "delay" abilities. Finally, some of them can just be used as a deterrent, such as casting a large AoE delayed ability to say "don't come into this territory".

However, I read [this](https://kotaku.com/final-fantasy-tactics-wasnt-supposed-to-have-casting-t-1519947150) article about Final Fantasy Tactics. It's an interview with a developer of a new indie game inspired by FFT, who was also a dev in FFT. Basically he says that casting time won't be in the new game, and was only in FFT because of technical limitations (the game needed time to load the graphics of certain spells). Also, I notice that it hasn't appeared in any of the later Tactics games by Square, nor in many other tactical games that are self-confessed "clones" of FFT (Fell Seal, for example). I basically haven't seen delayed abilities in any tactical turn-based game since FFT.

I also noticed, when playing the prototype of my game with some friends, that they were annoyed that some abilities didn't execute right away, even though it was advertised in their details that they have delay.

These things make me wonder if delay is an inherently bad mechanic, and that there's a good reason developers have been avoiding it since FFT. Perhaps it just feels bad or clunky on the side of the user, and reduces their overall gaming experience.

I have a few alternatives in mind. But my question is, **are delayed abilities in turn-based strategies generally a bad mechanic?**

Comment: I don't find categorizing mechanics into "good" and "bad" helps me make enjoyable games. Instead, I like to come at it from the angle of player experience: does this set of mechanics help me create the feeling of play that I want? If not, what are the unwanted feelings, what's causing them, and how can I bring things back to the target experience? So, rather than ask us to pass judgment on ALL delayed abilities in ALL turn-based strategy games, I'd recommend editing your question to focus instead on "How can I solve this balancing problem without annoying my players?" or something similar.

Comment: In discussing with the other moderators, we found that the phrasing of this question encourages opinion-based answers on whether the mechanic is "good" or "bad" rather than problem-solving answers focused on providing viable solutions to the issue you've observed in playtesting, so we've put it on hold for now. It's a valid topic, so I'd recommend posting it as a new question specific to solving your gameplay issue, rather than a referendum on the goodness of particular mechanics.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for the recommendation. But I was never looking for alternative suggestions. I really do want to know, specifically, if delayed actions in turn-based games are known to be a turnoff that developers deliberately avoid, because of some conventional wisdom. While it's true that the nature of my question is ultimately subjective, there are, in fact, game mechanics that are almost universally considered to be something developers ought to avoid. (For example, making enemies that can kill you with unpredictable cheap shots, exposing you to unskippable story elements.)

Answer (score 4):

My stance is there aren't inherently bad mechanics. Different mechanics appeal to different people. However, it sounds like that particular set of play testing *might* have found a disconnect between this particular mechanic & your particular game.

Here are some options:

**The play testers are not the intended audience.** The good news is this lets you keep your game as is. The bad news is it leads to new questions like:

- Who is the intend audience?
- How do you find them & connect with them?

These questions aren't necessarily easier to deal with & will need to be addressed if you want to have a viable product. (If you're not making your game as a product, the intended audience is probably yourself).

**The mechanic is not a good fit.** In this case to take it out, and see how it does. then check to see if it play tests well & if as a designer you are still evoking the experience you want. If it only sort of works, you may need to add in something else to add friction, evoke emotion, etc. Figuring this out can be one of the most difficult parts of design.

**The mechanic needs to be re-framed.** Sometimes the problem is context. If the mechanic is critical to your vision & you genuinely believe you're testing with the correct groups, look for ways to present the same thing in a different context. For instance, you mentioned cool downs. In a way, a cool down is a "first one free, delay on next". Not exactly the same, but it may be similar enough to keep your vision & simultaneously more appealing to your audience.

Along those lines, some other ideas might be:

- Offer both delayed & undelayed versions of an ability & tune to reflect risk / reward
- Instead of targeting units with a delayed ability, target terrain. This is akin to laying a trap & might 'feel' better to the players.

**The play testers are just reacting to push back.** It's not uncommon for players to want more than they have. Sometimes you want "just one more move" or to equip more than one trinket or to buy both of two mutually exclusive skills. Just because something is annoying doesn't mean the mechanic that caused it is un-fun. Again, it comes down to testing & designer expertise. Consider adding something that under certain circumstances, allows players to break the delay effect rule. If that addition is seen as a necessity, there's probably a problem. If it's just seen as great to have if you can get it, then things are probably okay.

Final comment on casting time not being included in the inspiration game: games often make choices to deal with constraints that might not be present to other developers at a later point in time &/or on a different platform. That doesn't mean the choices themselves were bad. Pixel graphics, permadeath, abstract logic games - these (and many more) were born out of necessity, but they still have value today.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems which can arise from abilities which require a preparation time.

- They unnecessarily draw out combats which are already decided. Let's say the player has a completely overpowered level 999 wizard who has that ability which single-handedly defeats the whole enemy army with one use, but it takes three rounds to cast. The player uses it in the beginning of the first round.

  The battle is decided now. There is nothing the enemy can do about it. Yes, the opponent *could* try to take out the wizard, but the AI isn't smart enough to realize that and the player is smart enough to make it impossible through clever positioning of their tanks. So there is no reason to continue that combat. Yet the player has to play through 3 pointless rounds of combat until the ability triggers and all enemies die.

  Never waste the player's time!
- It reduces the numbers of meaningful choices the player can make. When most of their army can't do anything on their turns because they are all preparing attacks, the player feels like they don't have anything to do. The player might even feel helpless because they should do something important to counter an enemy move, but they can't because all their units who could do it are caught up in casting.
- Attack with long delay might be too easy to counter, even accidentally. The intended target might move out of range. The target might get killed by some other ability. The caster might die. The target might get affected by a defense-enhancement buff which negates the damage. A better target might show up. These are all very frustrating and anti-climatic for the player. They anticipated to see something really cool, and when the time finally arrives, it falls flat.

Comment: I agree with your logic, but to be fair OP did state most abilities have delay = 0, meaning it's used right when the command is given. But like I said, you bring up a lot of valid problems with delays in general - can you include any insight as to determining when these potential problems might begin to manifest (i.e. figuring out how much is too much)?

Answer (score 0):

There are no good or bad styles.

It is the execution that matters. Often unique play styles are received badly (initially, due to prebuilt mindsets) but gain good traction later on.

But, if you think that player base (your friends) do not like delay based abilities, then you can definitely try other alternative and check which has better response.

Cheers..